# Passing Arguments to Spyder for debugging file

Tags: python, spyder

I want to pass arguments in Spyder IDE with IPython to debug the file but the input arguments passing will be different

Driver.py -in "C:\Desktop\" -out "C:\Desktop\" -f 65 -f2 64

How can i pass the arguments, so that i can be able to debug the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `run > configure`

Tick `command line options` and type in the arguments in the space.

Comment: If the arguments inputs are like -in "inputpath" -out "outputpath" also can we go through the command like arguments. Usually filename.py arg1 arg2 will be passed through the command line options

Comment: i don't think the double quotes are necessary, but i'm not sure. you need to `import sys` then command line arguments will be available in the form of a list in `sys.argv`

Comment: Thanks for your file. sys.argv works well in my case. sys.argv('Driver.py','-in','inputpath','-out','outputpath')

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you are looking for (in spyder).

For my function, I have several arguments, to pass multiple arguments on spyder to debug I pass debugfile('filePath', args='--argN1=argV1 --argN2=argV2', wdir='coreFolderPath')

Comment: Note, I was able to debug like this: 
debugfile('filePath', args='--argN1 argV1 --argN2 argV2', wdir='coreFolderPath')
So that I can copy paste args exactly as I would execute in a terminal.